# make a simple string builder UI

Tags: user-interface

I want to make a user interface for a string builder that I want to build for some users. The problem is the users sometimes have zero tech back ground. I want to know when I am not making it too complicated for my users to understand.

For example I want include a filter option for users to choose what computers they would like to select for a virus scan under a domain. Now I have to create a string builder that look like something like This

***  "user input content" * or

*** "user input" or

"user input" * "user input2" *

etc

now all I can think about is to give the user something like

name contains **_____** ;
which only covers  * "content" *

This lead me thinking about create a customized string builder for users to grab all the computers they want to scan.

eg. build your own filter **______**  then  provide a list of pre-defined keywords such as before, contain, anything,  after that users can select and add their own words behind these keywords as filters.  But then I am scared that is much too complicated as they would not know how. So I need help trying to find out When is it too complected or not for general public and if possible some suggestions on the particular case I have listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider something like what Brett Victor did with his [Proposition 21](http://worrydream.com/ExplorableExplanations/) example where the text is largely in place with default values already filled in, but where there are user controls to interactively adjust the values.

Alternately, you could just have a single field which, without any special characters, does a simple "contains" search across the relevant fields, but which supports additional syntax (described by a '?' button) for your more advanced users.

Comment: Yeah I was doing that initially but I don't have a lot of space to do that for the UI I am modifying to. I am thinking about maybe just leaving a contain____ for users and maybe an advanced option which will open up a string builder on the side for users to play with if they are tech enough. what you think

Comment: Hard for me to make a recommendation without more context (e.g., knowing your users, your specific app, etc.), but if you're feeling very uncertain, make a few different mockups of various options and user test them with your intended audience to see which works best.

Comment: I'd keep in mind, though, that your "tech savvy" users will probably understand using wildcards and such without needing a UI-driven builder, and your "non-savvy" users won't even understand the UI-driven builder.  So, building one is probably a waste of time for both parties.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now so probably going to just use contain and leave advanced as a play ground for advanced users to use wild cards to specify their own needs